# App Rejected for iCloud Backup Flagging

Tags: ios, storage, icloud

My app has a few in-app purchases that downloads video content to the /Documents folder. I recently submitted an update to the app and was rejected because I did not flag the video files to not be backed up to iCloud. I succesfully implemented the flagging but I am still confused by this statement in Apple's documentation:

Important The new "do not back up" attribute will only be used by iOS 5.0.1 or later. On iOS 5.0 and earlier, applications will need to store their data in /Library/Caches to avoid having it backed up. Since this attribute is ignored on older systems, you will need to insure your app complies with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines on all versions of iOS that your application supports.

My app supports iOS 3.2 and later, so do I need to account for different versions of iOS in my code or is implementing the do not backup flag enough to pass for App Store approval? I really don't want to drop support for versions earlier than 5.0.1.

Please help!

Comment: the tech not for flagging is sometimes difficult to find (so here's a link for anyone who ends up here looking for it): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Answer (score 4):

The correct behavior for your app is to place the files in Library/Caches on OSes prior to 5.0.1, and place it into Documents with the "do not backup" flag in 5.0.1 or later. the downside of using Library/Caches is the files will be wiped when the user upgrades the app (so they'd better be able to re-download them). But the upside is you won't be bloating their backups with files that shouldn't be backed up.

Note that on 5.0.1 or later if you detect that the files aren't there, you should check their pre-5.0.1 location before downloading them, in case the user just upgraded their OS.

Comment: So I'm going to get rejected unless I account for different versions? That seems kind of ridiculous. Storing files in /Documents was fine pre iOS 5. The only issue would be in 5.0.0 where the files would still technically get backed up to iCloud, but isn't that Apple's fault?

Comment: @reaelm32: I can't say for a fact whether you'll get rejected, but what I described is what you *should do* for the best user experience. And no, /Documents wasn't "fine" pre-iOS 5, Apple just got more strict about rejecting apps that backed up files that didn't need backing up, around the same time as they introduced the new "do not backup" flag in 5.0.1.

Comment: "Fine" and not "fine" are kinda irrelevant I think to @reaelm32 (I think). The issue is the PAIN involved in the change of behaviour. I'm sure it will all be great once we have all updated our document save methods :-/ - +1 for succinct explanation.

Comment: The forum seems to have contradicting answers to this problem all over the place. Some say that flagging is enough while some say that different versions must be accounted for. I will try submitting it with just flagging and see what the outcome is.

Comment: It is also important to note, you have to use a different flag in 5.1 as the traditional 'do not backup' flag has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The concern area is the iOS 5.0, which supports iCloud, but does not recognizes “do not backup” attribute. In this case, all the data of the app inside documents directory is likely to get backed up to iCloud.
For the iOS versions below 5.x:

- the iCloud backup is not valid.
- the "do not back up" flag is not relevent. It would not produce any warnings during compilation.

Hence the data can be kept in the documents directory, with "do not back up" flag appropiately added to the contents (files/folders), for all the versions.
The problem is for the version 5.0 only.