# What's the proper way to access a canned app resource that can be updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, appstore-approval

We have an iOS app which uses core data and we are populating the application data with a initial database. (SQLite). And later it will download the data from internet and update the database. We are copying the SQLite database to Documents folder. Apple says this is incorrect since files in the Documents folder will automatically backup to iCloud. They don't allow it unless those files are user created ones.

Solutions they have mentioned.

1. Set a flag to the file(On our case databse) that it wont get backup to iCloud. But this will work only in iOS 5.1 and we cant do that. we need to support iOS 4 and above. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)
2. Maintain the files(our case its database) in the temp folder. But they mentioned to delete whatever we put on temp folder on app exit. Again this is not the solution.

But my question is if we dont delete that what's the problem? what will happen to temp folder, when users are updating to the next app version from AppStore? Will it delete the contents or will it keep whatever its on the temp folder on app update?

Or anyone one have any other solution to this problem? Appreciate your help alot.

Comment: I didn't realize it synchronizes all the app documents but forbidden. Why is apple shooting it's own legs ?! I'm afraid the device might erase the cache data even before the app update.

Comment: Yes. we cant rely on cache folder. Documentation says OS may erase the contents at any given time.

Comment: To be honest, that's just a stupid situation, seems we'll have to store all the sqlite databases, xml configuration files, user session information and all other stuff at NSUserDefaults :(

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850069/app-rejected-for-icloud-backup-flagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documentation here is the solution I feel as correct.

--> iCloud and iTunes do not back up the contents of the following directories:

/AppName.app

/Library/Caches

/tmp

--> Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

/Documents

/Library

So I'm copying my initial database in to the Library/Caches. And do any updation on top of that database. But I feel if the device is running on low disk spaces it might delete the contents of cache folder. In that case I check for the database existence and I copy again if it's not there. (As a precaution). But in this case user might lose some of his data. But still Apple haven't provided a proper guide for this.

Answer (score 1):

I actually see two solutions to your problem.

1. Set a flag to your file ONLY when on iOS 5.1+, if the OS is less than 5.1, don't do it.
2. Read the documentation about saving files to disk, temp and Documents aren't the only two places you can store info in. On said documentation file it should say when are contents of each folder going to be deleted.

Comment: Issue is we have to support older iOS's beginning from iOS 4.

Comment: Why would that be an issue? You can just do something like `if(os >= 5.1) setFlag();`. That's pseudo-code, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try to read the database from the Documents folder? If it's there, great, you're in business. If it's not there then you must not have downloaded a newer version than the one that came with the app, so open the database in the app bundle instead.

Comment: This is not the correct way. As you say if we put the writeable database copy to Documents folder again they might reject. In fact thats what we are doing now. Appreciate you can read the question again.

Comment: You didn't say that you were writing into the database. Once you do that, it becomes a user file and something that *should* be backed up to iCloud. If the database is large and the amount of data that the user might change is relatively small, then it'd be better to write the user data to a separate database and manage both (easy with Core Data, maybe not quite so easy with SQLite).